# Using Ansible, can we edit kernel level setting?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

How can we set kernel settings using Ansible playbooks?

I have gone through `ansible.posix.sysctl` module, but I am not able able to find `threads.max`.

Comment: Can you specify in more detail what you trying to do and achieve? As well what do you mean with "kernel level setting"? Do you mean something like the kernel boot parameter, the kernel command line? Or do you mean your kernel configuration and configured kernel options? Since you mentioned `sysctl`, what were you not able to find?

Comment: Suppose  I have to edit threads.max setting can we do using ansible.

Answer (score 0):

According the already mentioned [`ansible.posix.sysctl`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/sysctl_module.html#examples) you can just use something like

```yaml
- name: Set kernel max. threads
  sysctl:
    name: kernel.threads-max
    value: '65535'
```

You may have a look into further roles and documentation like

**Further Readings**

- [Ansible Galaxy `linux-system-roles`](https://galaxy.ansible.com/linux-system-roles)
- [`kernel_settings`](https://galaxy.ansible.com/linux-system-roles/kernel_settings)
- [Using Ansible roles to permanently configure kernel parameters](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/using-ansible-roles-to-permanently-configure-kernel-parameters_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel)